# Coverage As -> JUnit Test in Eclipse Oxygen reports NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, junit, jacoco

When I run a JUnit 4 test using Code Coverage from within the Eclipse IDE, All I get is a dialog saying "An internal error occurred during: "Launching AlgebraicNumberTest".
java.lang.NullPointerException"

The same JUnit test runs fine under the debugger or using just plain run or from a gradle command line. Code coverage works fine when running the main application  rather than JUnit tests. I just can't get Code Coverage and the JUnit test to work together. They were working together on this project at one point several months ago. I don't know what's changed.

I'm using JUnit 4.12 and Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).

*** * * UPDATE * * ***

I found the Eclipse log file at %USERPROFILE%\eclipse-workspace.metadata.log.

Here's the exception detail from the log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2018-07-17 20:43:33.964
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching AlgebraicNumberTest".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.visualvm.launcher.java.VisualVMJUnitDelegate.launch(VisualVMJUnitDelegate.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.eclemma.core.launching.CoverageLauncher.launch(CoverageLauncher.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about where to find Eclipse's log file. I've added the details from the log file to the original post. Hope they're helpful to someone.

Comment: Since stack trace contains `org.eclipse.visualvm` could you try to uninstall VisualVM Eclipse Plugin ?

Comment: I uninstalled the "VisualVM Launcher Feature 1.1.2" plugin and it seems to have resolved the problem that I originally posted. I have used VisualVM in the past, but not often. Now I guess I'll have to check and see how that is affected, but at least my original issue is resolved for now. Thanks.

Comment: Reported to _VisualVM_ team as a [bug #104](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/104).

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled the "VisualVM Launcher Feature 1.1.2" plugin as suggested by @Godin. That seems to have resolved the problem that I originally posted.

I plan to eventually reinstall VisualVM. If it causes any problems, I'll post a new question.

Thanks all.